# How to simulate an hover event, using JavaScript or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to simulate the hover of the mouse over an element using JS or any other library.

I created this for the example and added some CSS to see when the `<p>` is hovered :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hover test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .red:hover {
            color:red;
        }

        .red:focus {
            color:green;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="red">test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

So when you put your finger onto the text, it gets red.

I tried some JQuery functions such as `mouseover()` and `hover()` but those are events.

I'd simply like to make the text red using some JS instructions.

Comment: why? when you can just set the class :/

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I don't get what you mean

Comment: What I mean is, in real life code you would never need to do this, instead you would simply set/toggle the class on the element, you dont need to go through the mouse api to set something, also would do it in CSS not in a js hover event, unless your looking to support CSSv1 etc

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I wouldn't ask if I don't need to...

Comment: Then probably an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: ^ Seconded. @lenr, perhaps you can provide your reason for needing this in the question? It's likely that there's a simpler and/or better way to accomplish your end-goal, however you're restricting your answers by not giving us the full picture.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
function simulateMouseover() {
  var event = new MouseEvent('mouseover', {
    'view': window,
    'bubbles': true,
    'cancelable': true
  });
  var myTarget = document.querySelector('.red'); 
  var canceled = !myTarget.dispatchEvent(event);
  if (canceled) {
    // A handler called preventDefault.
    alert("canceled");
  } else {
    // None of the handlers called preventDefault.
    alert("not canceled");
  }
}

function mouseOverBehaviour() {
    myElement = document.querySelector('.red'); 
     // attach mouseover event listener to element
    myElement.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
        // change the color of the font
        event.target.style.color = "red";
    });  
    // call the simulation
    setTimeout(simulateMouseover,3000);
}

mouseOverBehaviour();
```

Comment: Mmh, it turns my text into red but thanks to the ```event.target.style.color = "red";``` line, right ? Not automatically by the CSS

Answer (score -1):

```
$("p").hover(function(){
  $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
  }, function(){
  $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
});
```

jQuery can accomplish this as well. Have fun. let me know if you have questions

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_hover.asp